# Responsive Web-design media queries points vs pixels

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have created my website with html, css and javascript and designed it for iPhone X to start off. My website is going to target on Instagram so my main targets are all types of mobile devices. I'm using media queries in css and I want to check for screen height. I'm not sure but it sounds like a good approach for me because for example iPhones don't differ that much in screen width as they do in screen height.

This is my way of approach in css:

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 481px) and (max-height:666px){*css*}
```

This should be a query for iPhone 5, but I got really confused by points vs pixels so I was hoping some of you can help me out.

Google chrome shows me the screen size of iPhone 5 as 320 x 568. I was guessing these are supposed to be points but it works just fine with my media query entered in pixels while screen size of iPhone 5 in pixels should be 640 x 1136 pixels.

My media query for iPhone 5 works just fine in Google Chrome iPhone 5 "setup" but I also have a test iPhone 5 at home where responsivity seems not working at all.

So before continuing my responsive design I wanted to have this clear.. Why is this? Is Google Chrome showing points or pixels? Should I use points or pixels in my media queries? Why does it work with pixels in css when they are completely different when I google screen sizes?

I would still consider myself as a beginner so I would really appreciate not too complicated answers.

Thank you!

Comment: I always browse to resizemybrowser.com, which gives you css pixels (use the inner values). This is a consistent value. Obviously you should not rely on chrome only, but at least do safari and firefox. Nobody is showing points to my knowledge.

Comment: @Yishmeray I tried your website and when I tried iPhone 4 preset it tells me this "Resized to 400 x 377 instead of 640 x 960 because the available width and height of your screen isn't enough." How is my screen not enough when I'm on my MacBook?

Comment: The thing to do is NOT to use the buttons all across the page. JUST USE the readout on the bottom where it says Current Inner. Obviously maximize your browser first, if you have that option.